# Get duplicate object key's value and replace/return with only one from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out how to get duplicate object key's value and replace/return with only one from JSON among other object keys and return as an array finally.

**NOTE:** *This is a returned data from a JSON result.*

Example below.

```
const obj = { id: 71, books: 'Things fall apart' }
{ id: 71, books: 'The Namesake' }
{ id: 71, books: 'The Secret Life of Bees' }
{ id: 417, books: 'The Namesake' }
{ id: 417, books: 'State of Wonder' }
{ id: 22, books: "Americanah" }
{ id: 22, books: 'Things fall apart' }
```

**What I Have In Mind To Archieve After Getting the Above Data**

```
[
  {
    "id": 71,
    "books": [
      "Things fall apart",
      "The Namesake",
      "The Secret Life of Bees"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 417,
    "books": [
      "The Namesake",
      "State of Wonder"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "books": [
      "Americanah",
      "Things fall apart"
    ]
  }
]
```

Thanks as you help me out solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with a `reduce` and `findIndex`:

```js
const arr = [
 { id: 71, books: 'Things fall apart' },
 { id: 71, books: 'The Namesake' },
 { id: 71, books: 'The Secret Life of Bees' },
 { id: 417, books: 'The Namesake' },
 { id: 417, books: 'State of Wonder' },
 { id: 22, books: "Americanah" },
 { id: 22, books: 'Things fall apart' }
];

const res = arr.reduce((a, {id, books}) => {
    const index = a.findIndex(item => item.id === id);

    if (index === -1) {
 a.push({id, books: [books]});
    } else {
 a[index].books.push(books);
    }

    return a;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: It returns exactly what did you want to return to your question, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Stan50 welcome to Stack Overflow

```
      const arrayUnique = Array.from(
        obj
          .reduce(
            (acc, item) => (
              acc.set(item['id'], item)
            ),
            new Map()
          )
          .values()
      );
```

The reduce() method executes a reducer function that executes on each element in the array.
We have accumulator (acc) and current Value (item). 
Our reducer functions returned value is assigned to the accumulator (in this case we have initalValue and that's new Map() so this will be the first one when a callback is called) and then we set  (acc.set(item['id'], item) => for this id we set current item), and this accumulator is remembered across each iteration throughout the array.
Using Map is important because of its preservation of order.
And at the end, you use Values that only get objects and Array.from that create an array from these unique by id objects

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, the solution you gave only get every last key's value for a particular.
This was also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You mean obj is an array? Better to name it something like `records`. Also, `books` should be named `book` or `bookName` as it's not an array!

Anyways, you can solve it using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as shown below:

```
const result = obj.reduce((accumulator, record) => {
    const { id, books } = record;
    const existingRecord = accumulator.find(storedRecord => storedRecord.id === id);
    if (existingRecord) {
        existingRecord.books.push(books);
    } else {
        accumulator.push({id, books: [books]});
    }
    return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Umm, can you show what obj is? Some JSON or maybe paste some of it here